# iOS Smart Banner not showing anymore

Tags: ios, smartbanner

I recently setup the iOS smartbanner, using the link below:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html
The banner worked perfectly, but whenever I installed the app using the banner, went back and deleted the app, the smart banner would disappear and would not come back no matter what. In addition to that, clicking the 'X' button would also result in the same fate. Is there any way to make the banner not disappear, or are their any other smartbanners that we can link my app with, particularly to open the app as well.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: The smart banner would come back if I installed the app. It would ask me if I wanted to open the app.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked extensively in this and from what I've found, this is the business logic of the smartbanner. It stops the smartbanner from spamming you again and again with the app's advertisement. Once you have clicked the "view app" button, this fires the same event as closing the app, hence spam protection business logic comes into effect.
From what I've checked, there isn't any alternative with respect to opening the app as well.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, this is more like how the smartbanner is designed to stop spam. Nothing you can do about it as of now.
It comes back again once you install the app because now it is not spamming, but just giving you a convenient way to open an already installed app.